# Set image maximum file size with validator

Tags: image, upload, yii2

I am implementing image upload in Yii2 using File Input Widget as shown in http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput. May I know how to set the uploaded file size limit?

I have added:

```
['image', 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 1024],
```

inside the model's `rules()` but it does not seem to work.

Hope someone can advise. Thanks.

In View:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation' => false,  'options' => [ 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>


<?php

echo $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*', 'multiple'=>true],
    'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif','png']]
]);

?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

In Controller:

```
    $model = new IMAGEMODEL();  

    Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/uploads/PROJECT/';


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // get the uploaded file instance. for multiple file uploads
        // the following data will return an array
        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');


        // store the source file name
        $model->FILENAME = $image->name;
        $ext = end((explode(".", $image->name)));

        // generate a unique file name

        $model->AVATAR = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";
        $model->STD_ID=$_POST['IMAGEMODEL']['STD_ID'];


        // the path to save file, you can set an uploadPath
        // in Yii::$app->params (as used in example below)
        $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->AVATAR;

        if($model->save()){
            $image->saveAs($path);
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Image uploaded successfully');
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id'=>$id]);

        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Fail to save image');
        }
    }
```

In Model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['STD_ID', 'FILENAME'], 'required'],
        [['FILENAME'], 'string'],
        [['LAST_UPD_ON'], 'safe'],
        [['STD_ID'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['LAST_UPDATE_BY'], 'string', 'max' => 150],

        [['image', 'FILENAME'], 'safe'],
        ['image', 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 1],

    ];
}
```

Comment: What size you want to set as limit? 1 Gb or 1 Mb?

Comment: i want to set limit as 2Mb..

Comment: Did my answer help you? Is the problem solved now?

Comment: i am unable to use that method as the system still does not stop me from uploading larger file size images and so i had to use the manual check as mentioned previously...

Comment: I think the error is somewhere else, since that validation rule does the same exact check for maximum size.

Comment: i guess so, but i couldn't figure where is the error occurring too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1)** [maxSize](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html#$maxSize-detail) parameter expects number of bytes. In your example you set 1 Gb. For 2 Mb it should be:

```
['image', 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2],
```

**2)** Also check `upload_max_filesize` INI setting.

**3)** Make sure pass the instance of [yii\web\UploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html) by calling [getInstance()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstance%28%29-detail) method (for multiple files use [getInstances()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstances%28%29-detail)) before validate:

```
$this->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image');
```

Comment: Hi i tried but still is able to upload file sizes >2mb. The strange thing is when i check the $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image'); $image->size returns me 0kb while all other parameters such as $image->name and $image->extension returns the correct values

Comment: Show the rest of the code: how you handle uploaded image, how you display it in form.

Comment: uploaded controller and view

Comment: `'multiple' => true` - so you want upload multiple images or just one?

Comment: at first the intention is to upload multiple but i get this in source code for chrome and for IE "<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Note:</strong> Your browser does not support file preview and multiple file upload. Try an alternative or more recent browser to access these features.</div>" so i decided to go for just one for now

Comment: In that case remove this option from plugin settings.

Comment: have removed it so now it is echo $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*'],
    'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif','png']]
]);  but still my 4mb file is able to upload successfully

Comment: Try with regular file input without extensions. Also I don't get it - it allows you submit 4 Mb file or just upload it through extension before submitting?

Comment: i retested, realise the 4mb file did not get uploaded to the server folder but the row was inserted into the database. How do i prevent insertion to the database if file is not uploaded to server?

Comment: Current code should already prevent that, because you save file only after validation and saving record in database.

Comment: is there any way i could check the size of the file and block it before saving? $image->size does not seem to cater to it.

Comment: It's provided by PHP. See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UploadedFile.php#L204 and https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UploadedFile.php#L217. I think the problem is somewhere else. This validation rule should work OK.

Comment: my guess is my server is refusing entry for files>2mb. Am checking with my dba regarding this. the validation rule does not seem to have any effect on it, seems to be the same when i comment it off. The 4mb file still is refused entry. Is there any way i can display to user about file size exceeding limit set?

Comment: i tried setting in rule ['image', 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 1], and uploaded a 1.46mb image, the file is uploaded successfully in server and database row added as well. The validation does not seem to be working.

Comment: Have added here the rules set in my model. Can assist to see if anyting is wrong?

Comment: I tested it just know and validation with maximum size work fine for me. Seems like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: After my dba updated the upload limit to 128mb on apache, i added:  if($image->size >= 2097152) {
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Image exceed size limit');
return $this->redirect(['view', 'id'=>$id]);} solves the problem. Nevertheless thanks for your help~

Comment: You shouldn't do this check manually. Validator does it for you. You can see it here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/validators/FileValidator.php#L216. Anyways glad to help. If the answer was helpful, don't forget to upvote and accept so the others can know too.

Comment: If you want to change default error message for exceedeed file size, change `tooBig` parameter.

Comment: ok thanks!.sorry but how do i implement validator in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "this case"?

Comment: Exactly as in answer, just set proper `maxSize` instead of checking it manually.

Comment: hi arogachev, can u kindly help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358398/how-to-implement-yii2-popover-x-on-gridview-view-and-update-button please? have been stuck with it for 2 days. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can also set image dimension using this along with max file size

```
['image', 'image', 'minWidth' => 250, 'maxWidth' => 250,'minHeight' => 250, 'maxHeight' => 250, 'extensions' => 'jpg, gif, png', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2],
```

this allows you to upload maximum of 2mb with 250px width and 250px height

Answer (score 0):

You can set in your view `pluginOptions` of the FileInput widget this property: `'maxFileSize' => 2048`. It will be something like this:

```
widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['multiple'=>true, 'accept'=>'image/*'],

    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png'],
        ...
        'maxFileSize' => 2048,
        ...
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I am using "image extension", it works fine, as far as I upload images having size relatively small, like 2mbs etc it resize my image just the way i want, but problem starts when i upload big images having size 3mb or above, even my validation rules does not help me. I tried setting my upload_max_size to 256 Mb and memory limit to 512 Mb but when i try to upload a big image my page page just refresh. Is it a bug in framework or what.