# Gridview with popup

Tags: gridview, yii2

I want to design an custome popup ( not like delete) in gridview with jquery button click event 
button is in action column ob gridview

how can add popup with id of each row

Comment: Use bootstrap modal. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470166/yii2-modal-dialog-on-gridview-view-and-update-button-shows-same-content-for-both).

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
Insert

```
use yii\helpers\Url;  
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
```

Into u'r index.php

```
[
    'class'    => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'header'   => 'Action',
    'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {your_link}',
    'buttons'  => [

        'your_link' => function ($url, $model) {
            $url = Url::to(['controller / action', 'id' => $model->id]);

            return Html::a(' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" title = "Tooltip Name" ></span> ', 'javascript:void(0)', ['class' => 'anyClassName', 'value' => $url]);
        },
    ],
],
```

Define modal and Register this JS into you'r index file

```
<?php 

Modal::begin([
    'id'     => "modal",
    'header' => '<h3>Assign Farmers to other Farm Mitra</h3>',
]);

echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end();


$this->registerJs(
    "$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
            $('.list').click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault(); //for prevent default behavior of <a> tag.
               $('#modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').load($(this).attr('value'));
           });
        });
    ");

?>
```