# Request.Form returns no value despite data being entered in field

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Modal "addModal" that opens from a button click. When I add a name to the name field and the Save the button (btnSubmit_Click) my Request.Form("nameid") gives a null value. I am new to C# and ASPX so there may be something obvious I am missing here.

I have two modals in the same page and was having issues earlier getting both to postback properly ([earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241070/the-second-modal-in-my-aspx-file-doesnt-post-when-clicking-submit-button)) and am trying to workaround this problem.

I had to change my earlier function to receive an HtmlButton instead of a Button as this is was the sender type.

Any direction would be appreciated.

***ASPX:***

```
<div id="addModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" method="POST" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
        <form role="form">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="nameid" id="nameid" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitItem" class="btn btn-primary" OnServerClick="btnSubmit_Click" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server">Save</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

***C#:***

```
public void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                   
        HtmlButton clickedButton = (HtmlButton)sender;
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + Request.Form("nameid")  +"');</script>");                        
        if ( clickedButton != null)
        {
            string name = String.Format("{0}",      Request.Form["nameid"]);    
        }               
    }
```

Comment: You haven't given your form a name or an action. Is this in an asp.net webform or is this just an html file?

Comment: This is a bootstrap modal form that is opened after a button click on the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to switch to actual aspnet Controls. Like a TextBox.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="nameidLabel" runat="server" Text="Name" AssociatedControlID="nameid"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <asp:TextBox ID="nameid" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then in code behind

```
public void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alerter", "alert('" + nameid.Text + "')", true);
}
```

And if you use webforms, remove that `form` tag. There should be only one on the page.

And use `ScriptManager` instead of `Response.Write`

Comment: trying that now.

Comment: I tried the above and still get no value for the nameid field. I removed the form tags and tried the TextBox.

Comment: The problem was I had 2 sets of form tags. Removing this made it work. Thanks for the simple solution.

Comment: Yes, webforms can only have one form. And you should look into the other types of Controls as well. There are Buttons also.

Answer (score 1):

`nameid` needs a 'name' attribute.

input type="text" **name="nameid"** id="nameid" class="form-control"

```
<div id="addModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" method="POST" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
        <form role="form">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="nameid" id="nameid" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitItem" class="btn btn-primary" OnServerClick="btnSubmit_Click" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server">Save</button> 
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added this and it still does not return a value for the nameid key. I updated the above.