# stop pjax to replace a link with return data

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

i have put below code

```
<?php
/* helpers */
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\URL;

use yii\grid\GridView;
/* widgets */
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

Pjax::begin(['id'=>'view_member']);
    echo Html::a('view',URL::to(['view','id'=>$model->_id]),['class'=>'show']);
Pjax::end();
```

this code show a anchor link and after click of this link it replace a link with data return by ajax.

I don't want to replace a link with data. I need link as it is with return data.

Comment: please update your question with a sample

Comment: please check image link @scaisEdge

Comment: The behavior seem correct  the pjax repalce the destination ..  could be you want use action column for modal see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358398/how-to-implement-yii2-modal-dialog-on-gridview-view-and-update-button

Comment: `Pjax::begin(['id'=>'view_member', 'enablePushState' => false]);`

Comment: @XiaosongGuo  thank you for your reply but i am talking about link not url please check image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd either return the link with the modal HTML or target the link from the `Pjax` widget, [linkSelector](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html#$linkSelector-detail).

```
echo Html::a('view',URL::to(['view','id'=>$model->_id]),['id' => 'view_link', 'class'=>'show']);
Pjax::widget(['id'=>'view_member', 'linkSelector' => '#view_link']);
```

Comment: thank you @alex it's work...i also solve using a trick i have create a div with same id of pjax