# Checkbox column not Working in yii2 gridview with Modal

Tags: php, gridview, checkbox, yii2

I have a gridview . It displays the departments available in a college.
When I click the row it populate the modal and Its shows the lecturer available for the selected department in kartik gridview .

In that I am using the kartik/grid/CheckboxColumn.

But when I click the Checkbox and get the selected rows through javacript, It doesn't return primary key associated with the record.
If I execute the gridview without modal , then it works fine

```
           $this->registerJs("     
           $('#lect-logout').click(function() {
           var key = $('#w0-container').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    alert(key);                                                                                                                                   
$.post(          
    '?r=lec-logout/logout',         
    {       
        id: $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows'),
          },  
    function (data) {
        alert("ok");

    }   
);
```

});
    ");

How to use that checkbox with the modal. Even I click select all option in checkbox. It doesn't select all the rows.

### Controller Code

```
     public function actionIndex()
    {
            $searchModel = new CollegeSearch();
            $dataProvider =    $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
            return $this->render('index', [ 'searchModel' => $searchModel,  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);                                    
    }

   public function actionLecture()                                                                                                               
    {
            $model = new Accounts();
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
            }
            else{
            $searchModel = new LectureSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

            return $this->renderAjax('lecture', ['searchModel' => $searchModel,'dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
            }
    }
```

### View CODE

index.php

```
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'rowOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
            return ['id' => $model['account_id'], 'onclick' => 'getrow(this.id)'];
    },
            'columns' => [
            'displayname',
            ],
            ]); ?>

   <?php Modal::begin([
'id' => 'show-agents-modal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
'header' => '<h4 class="modal-title">View</h4>',
   ]);
      Modal::end(); ?>
```

Lecture.php

```
       <div class="pull-right">
      <?= Html::Button('Logout',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','id'=>'lect- logout']); ?>
     </div>
   <br>
        <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      //        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [

         'first_name,

        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: put your gridview code

Comment: Try this code `var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');`

Comment: @GAMITG Its not working. It shows data not defined error and find my code. That I used.

Comment: @GAMITG I can't select al the record in single selection, in the header check box.

Comment: Use `yii\grid\CheckboxColumn` instead of `kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn`

Comment: @InsaneSkull I did that also.. It doesn't work

Comment: show `yii\grid\CheckboxColumn`, what you tried with it?

Comment: Just I am using Yii/grid/CheckboxColumn instead of kartik\grid/checkboxColumn

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [yii\grid\CheckboxColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html) then try this :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 
                'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return ['value' => $model->your_id];
                },
            ],
         .
         .
])?>
```

Comment: Actually my question is that checkbox column doesn't work wen I show the gridview within the modal.

Comment: @Bhuvanesh. Tty this [idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358398/how-to-implement-yii2-modal-dialog-on-gridview-view-and-update-button), if you don't understand then add comment.

Comment: That is for View and Update.. That I understood and I already did that. My problem, I am showing the grdiview in modal. Not the view form or update form

Comment: @Bhuvanesh. I knew you will not get it. you can tick checkbox in modal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114332/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-bhuvanesh).